# Keep getting VisaIOErrors after crash, unless device and ipython are rebooted

Tags: ipython, visa, pyvisa

We are controlling a Keithley DMM6500 using the pyVisa library. In our setup, we are keeping an iPython kernel running (through Spyder).

The problem we're running into is the following: whenever a function that interacts with the DMM encounters an unhandled exception (like a `KeyboardInterrupt`), any subsequent calls to the DMM result in the error `VI_ERROR_SYSTEM_ERROR (-1073807360): Unknown system error (miscellaneous error).`

In order to fix this, we have tried to call `device.clear()` and `device.close()` / `device.open()`, but this doesn't seem to work. Even rebooting the device does not work. The only thing that fixes the issue, it seems, is to completely restart our iPython kernel.

Is there any way to programmatically restore communication with the device, such that we can avoid having to reboot the ipython kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Some of your question is unclear so my answer might not help, however, it sounds like the terminal is locking the connection and you're loosing the reference.

The two way I have done this in the past:

1. Open the connection when talking to the device and close the connection when finished. This is useful if your connection is unstable but takes a fraction longer to open and close the connection a lot.

2)In your program you should have a try/except to handle the connection to the insturument and when the program errors you need to close the connection so that it doesn't become locked.

example:

```
try:
    run_program() 
except:
    close_connection_to_all devices() # build a function to clear connection to all devices
    dump_any_unsaved_data() # maybe you want to dump some of the variable to see what the data was when it errored for debug
```